# Issue with Removing characters from a string

Tags: c#, string, methods

I've seen many answers on how to deal with editing characters within a string with c#.

However, I need a reply which only considers using the string class method remove (also to avoid using the stringbuilder).

This is only so that I may see what the issue is with this specific code, which does not seem to get rid of a middle whitespace in a phone number. The code also removes any other character which is not a number.

I have been unable so far to understand why the whitespace or two adjacent whitespaces would not be removed. I suspect maybe the self assignment to the same string might be an issue, but I'm unsure.

```
//leave only the digits
for (int i = 0; i < enteredPhone.Length; i++)
{
     switch (enteredPhone[i])
     {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
           break;

        default:
             //gets rid of any other type of character
             enterPhone = enteredPhone.Remove(i, 1);
             break;
        }
   }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "However, I need a reply which only considers using the string class method remove (also to avoid using the stringbuilder)." You **need** explain this requirement. It doesn't make sense to the people who might help you.

Comment: OMG, if you're not going to use the advantages provided by the Base Class Library, why are you using C# and .Net at all? go ahead and do your programming [with butterflies](http://xkcd.com/378/).

Comment: When you remove like above you change your index `i` value. You need to adjust for that.

Comment: this can be a useful exercise of iterating through a container with changing number of items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"why the whitespace or two adjacent whitespaces would not be removed" - because all character indices after `i` are reduced by 1 when you `.Remove` `i`.

Walk the string backwards - from `Length-1` to `0`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to subtract 1 when you remove a caracter. Because if you remove the caracter in position 5 and i++ , the value of i now is 5, and the next caracter will be not found by the loop. Like this:

```
default:
         //gets rid of any other type of character
         enterPhone = enteredPhone.Remove(i, 1);
         i--;
         break;
```

Comment: `enterPhone` should be `enteredPhone` (the assignation), else the loop will be stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is incrementing index every time, even if you have removed non-digit character. In that case next character will have current index, but on next loop you are incrementing current index, thus skipping next character. Use `while` instead of `for`:

```
int index = 0;
while(index < enteredPhone.Length)
{
    switch (enteredPhone[index])
    {
        case '0':
        case '1':
        case '2':
        case '3':
        case '4':
        case '5':
        case '6':
        case '7':
        case '8':
        case '9':
            index++;
            break;

        default:                
            enteredPhone = enteredPhone.Remove(index, 1);
            break;
    }
}
```

Also you can use Char.IsDigit to simplify this loop:

```
int index = 0;
while(index < enteredPhone.Length)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(enteredPhone[index]))
    {
        index++;
        continue;
    }

    enteredPhone = enteredPhone.Remove(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your bizarre requirements:

```
Regex.Replace(inputString, @"\D", string.Empty)
```

Comment: BTW, `\D` is the same as `[^\d]`.

Comment: @Andy: To be expected... probabaly because I refused to accept the requirements of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var onlyDigits = new string(enteredPhone.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

should be a little more efficient than regex.

Comment: Why do you say it should be more efficient than a regex?

Comment: @wdosanjos Regex is regularly a pretty expensive way of doing things. I did a quick benchmark and the Regex answer above took 9-10 times longer than this answer.

Comment: @wdosanjos if the Regex answer was changed to optimize how the Regex is created, I was able to get it down to just 6 times the speed of this answer.

Comment: Regex is fast for complicated parsing but overkill for a simple operation like this

Answer (score 0):

You can also try.  But I believe the Linq or Regex solutions are better options.

```
//leave only the digits
for (int i = enteredPhone.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (!Char.IsDigit(enteredPhone[i]))
    {
       enterPhone = enteredPhone.Remove(i, 1);
    }
}
```